# Is this a case of PWM interference?

Tags: arduino, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I have a Electronic Speed Controller (ESC) being controlled with Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) from an Arduino.

When I put my hand close to the cables the signal goes screwy until I move my hands away. I checked for shorts but didn't find any. I don't have an oscilloscope or that would give me my answer.

**What's happening here?**

I also made [this video to help explain the situation](https://youtu.be/QtL_bOam5GM).

## Rough Schematic

[image: schematic]

## EDIT

*Adding working Arduino code for future visitors*

```
#include <SoftwareServo.h> // Download from http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Servo

SoftwareServo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

//int potpin = 0;  // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
int PIN = 2;
int val;    // variable to read the value from the analog pin

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myservo.attach(PIN);  // attaches the servo on pin 2 to the servo object
}

void loop()
{
  char r = Serial.read();
  String inStr = String(r);
  if(r > -1) {
    Serial.print("serial in: ");
    Serial.println(inStr);
  }

  if(r <= -1) {
    // void
  } else if(inStr == "h") { // high
    Serial.println("HIGH");
    digitalWrite(PIN, HIGH);
  } else if(inStr == "m") { // medium
    Serial.println("medium");
    myservo.write(90);
  } else if (inStr == "l") { // low
    Serial.println("LOW");
    digitalWrite(PIN, LOW);
  } else if (inStr.toInt() >= 0 && inStr.toInt() <= 9) {
    int val = inStr.toInt() * 20;
    Serial.println(val);
    myservo.write(val);
  }
  
//  float t = millis() / 100;
//  val = sin(t / 10) * 1000;//analogRead(potpin);            // reads the value of the potentiometer (value between 0 and 1023)
//  //  if(val < 0) val *= -1;
//  val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 179);     // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180)
//  val = millis() / 100;
//  myservo.write(val);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value
//  Serial.println(val);
//  delay(15);                           // waits for the servo to get there

  SoftwareServo::refresh();
}
```

Comment: Do you have schematics?

Comment: You should add your schematics.  It sounds like a capacitive node which you are coupling to.  For example the gate of an undriven mosfet.

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Show where the battery GND is connected to the Arduino GND and whether the Mac is on mains or not. (That may give a mains ground through the USB cable.)

Comment: @transistor Thanks for that info. I'm new to schematics so I'll draw up what I can.

Comment: I didn't know how to make the pairings in the schematic tool so I drew it up.

Comment: Which signal goes screwy? I can't see any ground connections on that schematic, nor power connections to the Arduino, unless it's USB powered.

Comment: The PWM signal goes screwy. You can see it better in the youtube video I posted. ESC is powered from lipo (red wire is +) and Arduino gets power from USB

Comment: But is there a ground connection between the Arduino and the ESC?

Comment: Ground as in the ground wire or a chassis ground? There's POS and GND wires from the ESC connected to the battery. The signal wire has 5V POS, GND, SIG but only the signal is connected to the arduino.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. ". . . The signal wire has 5V POS, GND, SIG but only the signal is connected to the arduino.". That sounds like three signals on one signal. Do you mean to say that there is only the one PWM wire between the ESC and the Arduino? Your drawing makes it look like there is a missing ground wire (only one wire between the ESC and the Arduino), and if so, I'm surprised that it works at all.

Comment: @Mark yes the only pwm wire is from the ESC to the arduino since the ESC gets power from the lipo battery. Normally the ESC gets an analog signal but I'm sending it pwm which works but I'm getting some goofy interference.

Comment: You are also sending it a lot of noise if you don't connect a wire between the ground of the Arduino and the ground of the ESC. Your finger is simply amplifying the noise.

Comment: @Mark - it's not really a case of sending "noise" but rather that without a ground reference the  PWM signal is effectively being weakly capacitively coupled into the speed control.  Of course a signal ground is required for reliable operation.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - of course you're right, but clearly noise is his problem, as his finger demonstrates. Otherwise, the weak capacitive coupling would be adequate. It is in the environment, and the capacitive coupling is not enough to shunt it to ground. He needs a ground wire.

Comment: We can agree on the need for a ground, but you seem to misunderstand both the subject of noise, and how the signal is sometimes getting through.

Comment: No, Sorry, Chris - After doing this for forty years, I understand noise. Sure, I'm oversimplifying, but I'm sure that when he puts his "hand close to the cables the signal goes screwy", that you would see the 60Hz coupling of noise (Ok, maybe you object to my using the term "noise" in this situation - so be it) from the AC line, if he had an oscilloscope. But to the ESC, the signal will look like noise.

Comment: @Mark I did more testing and found that if I get power from the arduino I get this unstable behavior. However, if I get the power from the ESC then everything works as expected. It makes sense that the ground be attached to where the signal is going which must have been why you asked your original question. If you have time to post an answer I'd like you to get the credit, if you don't have the time I'll put a note in saying that you lead to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer originated from a comment by @Mark*

**This is a `ground` issue.**

Even though the ESC will work without a `ground` from the Arduino, to make the `signal` stable I needed to accompany the `signal` wire from the Arduino with a `ground` wire from the Arduino.

Per my example I took the *disconnected* `ground` from the ESC and connected it to the **GND** from the Arduino.